# Google Webmaster Tools can't access robots.txt and the home page is "temporarily unreachable"

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, googlebot

My site http://goo.gl/xH2Ffy suddenly disappeared from Google search and Webmaster Tools says it can't access robots.txt. Fetch as Google says "temporarily unreachable" for robots.txt and even for the home page. The robots.txt tester throws the below error:

> You have a robots.txt file that we are currently unable to fetch. In such cases we stop crawling your site until we get hold of a robots.txt, or fall back to the last known good robots.txt file.

My website comes up fine in browser and even robots.txt comes up fine. What could be the reason?

My Robots.txt content:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /Admin/
Allow: /
```

I have not moved hosts recently. It was working fine and it happened suddenly.

Comment: Please share content of your robot.txt file  , also did you transfer/move your site recently?

Comment: Updated the content of robots.txt above. No i have not moved my site recently.

Comment: Check your .htaccess file - has anything been added?

Comment: I believe .htaccess is only for Apache. My hosting is on Windows server and the site uses ASP.Net.

Comment: Kindly check logs on server , I think some change done accidentally ..

Comment: For the record: It is not normally necessary to *allow* in your robots.txt file. It may help to simplify this just in case of confusion.

Comment: Go to search console of Google to your website. Left in Dashboard click on Crawl and click on robot.txt Tester. Check your current robots file.